# Cannot set session variable after AJAX POST request

Tags: php, ajax, session, fetch

I am sending an `AJAX POST request` to a `handleSession.php` the file which is meant to take the POST params and then add them to the session. However, the `handleSession.php file fails to update the session data`. Here is the `AJAX request code` which is working fine

```
var req = JSON.stringify({
   body:body,
   img:img,
   title:title,
   id:id,
   category:category}
);

fetch("handleSession.php", {
  method:"POST",
  body: req
})
.then((data) => data.text())
.then(data => JSON.parse(data))
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Here below is the handleSession.php file which should then parse the `$_POST` data to the session

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$arr = array(
  "title" => "",
  "img" => "",
  "body" => "",
  "id" => "",
  "category" => ""
);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key] = $data[$key];
}

$_SESSION["fav"] = $arr["title"];
//even if I say $_SESSION["FOO"] = "bar"; it still doesn't work

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

So on another page with `session_start()` and `ob_start()` at the top of the page i've said

```
if(isset($_SESSION["fav"])){
  echo $_SESSION["fav"];
}else{
  echo "Session fav not set";
}
```

And it will always go to the else condition

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what is the status code of the ajax call is it 200? Also what you are getting in response

Comment: Try a simple test, change this line `$_SESSION["fav"] =$arr["title"];
` to `$_SESSION["fav"] = 'testing';` and see what gets to the other page

Comment: even with the test case the session still doesn't save and I'm getting a 200 back with a JSON object

Comment: Try puttting `start_session()` before `ob_start()`. Or remove `ob_start()` completely, not sure why its there in the first place

Comment: @RiggsFolly it makes no difference